# Folium not showing Boundaries or Data

Tags: python, gis, geojson, folium

I am struggling to get Folium to show boundaries (if I ask it to show just Boundaries) and also data points, if I include those too. And I am hoping someone can assist in pointing me in the right direction.

I am just trying to teach myself Folium and have hit this brick wall.

I have a GeoJson file from the UKs ONS Geo Portal - [URL](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/ons::lad-dec-2021-gb-bfc/explore?location=55.217379%2C-3.265847%2C6.87)

Be warned, the GeoJson file does download at 130MB.

And I have a CSV file from the ONS data site that gives simple population totals at a local authority level. The GeoJson matches the CSV in terms of them both using the same area Id stamps.

This is a quick snippet of the csv file data...

[image]

So I am unsure as to why I cannot get Folium to display what I think it should display. I get no errors and the map displays, and saves fine. I just get a normal map output with no Boundaries and no data.

My code is as follows:

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import json

# Create the initial Map setup...
m = folium.Map(location=[54.38, -2.7], zoom_start = 6.499)

# Use json to open and read in the GeoJson file...
with open('eng.geojson') as f:
    gb = json.load(f)

# Change the existing column so that there is an 'id' attribute in the features...
for i in gb['features']:
    i['id'] = i['properties']['LAD21CD']

# Read in the data CSV using pandas
df = pd.read_csv('AdultPop.csv')

# Alter the columns so they are more readable...
cols = ['id','total']
df.columns = cols

# generate the Choropleth...
folium.Choropleth(geo_data = gb,
              data = df,
              columns = ['id','total'],
              key_on = 'feature.id',
              fill_color = 'YlGn',
              fill_opacity = 0.5
             ).add_to(m)

# Save the map to html file
m.save("map.html")

# also display the map in notebook...
m
```

And the output I get is just a standard map output with no boundaries and no data plotted.

It is probably something simple that I am going to kick myself about, but I just cannot seem to figure it out.

Map output is as follows:

[image]

**13/04/2023 Edit** - Unfortunately the suggested answer does not work - in fact I then get an error as 'geo.json' is not defined anywhere in my code...

[image]

If I assume you may have mentioned adding the following entry...

```
# Added Code...
folium.GeoJson(gb).add_to(m)

# generate the Choropleth...
folium.Choropleth(geo_data = gb,
                  data = df,
                  columns = ['id','total'],
                  key_on = 'feature.id',
                  fill_color = 'YlGn',
                  fill_opacity = 0.5,
                 ).add_to(m)
```

This still ends up in the very same blank map with no boundaries or data points.

**Further Edit** - having had a play about - whilst I still cannot get even just the boundaries to show using folium, if I mix folium and GeoPandas - the boundaries show using the following:

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

m = folium.Map(tiles='cartodbpositron',location=[54.38, -2.7], zoom_start = 6.499)

df = gpd.read_file('eng.geojson')

folium.Choropleth(geo_data = df).add_to(m)

m
```

and I get the boundaries...

[image]

So I really am struggling to see why they would show on Folium just by putting the GeoJson into a Dataframe first?

Comment: Have you tried `m = folium.Choropleth(geo_data...` ?

Comment: Hello - I have just tried this, but if I leave the ',add_to(m)' at the end of the new version, nothing appears in Jupyter - where as before the final call of 'm' would show the map. Now it shows nothing and nothing saves. If I do not put the '.add_to(m)' at the end, I get an error to state that the folium.Choropleth must be added to a map object. So unfortunately this does not seem to have worked, but thank you for the suggestion